# How to access the fetched object property that is encapsulated within the SQL function count()?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have the following function:

```
        public function count () {
            global $db;
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM posts";
            $result = $db->select($query);
            return $result;
        }
```

This then links to another function:

```
    public function select($query) {

        $results = $this->connection->query($query);

        while ($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
            $r[] = $obj;
        }
        if (!empty($r)) {
        return $r;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The output is in a form of an array of objects.

Normally I could access the property of that object to get the result.

$result[0]->property

But in this case, the property is encapsulated in the function count(). How can I access that property?

I have utilized a workaround by simply selecting the number of rows from the query. But I still want to know how can I access that property via COUNT().

```
        public function count () {
            global $db;
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
            $result = $db->initiate_query($query)->num_rows;
            return $result;
        }

        public function initiate_query($query) {

        $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        return $result;
    }
```

Thank you in advance,

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all try to use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) on fetched object. That should give you suggestions. I do believe that it is something like `$object->count` by default in most DBMS engines.

Second option (that I do really prefer in my code) is to use alias on `COUNT()`ed field:

```
SELECT COUNT(post_id) as tmp_value FROM posts
```

Then you should access it as predefined alias states: `$object->tmp_value`.

In the end you should get something like this:

```
public function count(){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(post_id) as tmp FROM posts";
    $result = $db->select($query);
    return $result[0]->tmp;
}
```